# How to merge two xml files by ID (in first as subnode value, in second as attribute)

Tags: php, xml

I have two XML files with this structure:

**first.xml**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>foo</id>
        <desc>lorem ipsum</desc>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>boo</id>
        <desc>lorem ipsum</desc>
    </item>
</items>
```

**second.xml**

```
<item_list>
    <item id="foo">
        <stock_quantity>20</stock_quantity>
    </item>
    <item id="boo">
        <stock_quantity>11</stock_quantity>
    </item>
</item_list>
```

and I need to combine them by the id so the ouput file would look like this:

**output.xml**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>foo</id>
        <desc>lorem ipsum</desc>
        <stock_quantity>20</stock_quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>boo</id>
        <desc>lorem ipsum</desc>
        <stock_quantity>11</stock_quantity>
    </item>
</items>
```

I need to use PHP and XML DOMDocument. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a board to request code or recommendations, its a board to come by with a specific problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplexml library to achieve that,

```
// loading xml to object from file
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file("first.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("second.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
// its core xml iterator for simplexml library
foreach ($xml1->children() as $items1) {
    $id = trim($items1->id); // trim to check with id matched in 2.xml
    foreach ($xml2->children() as $items2) { // iterating children of 2.xml
        if ($items2[0]['id'] == $id) { // simply checking attribute of id in 2.xml with 1.xml's id value
            foreach ($items2 as $key => $value) {
                $items1->addChild($key, (string) ($value)); // adding children to 1.xml object
            }
        }
    }
}
$xml1->asXml('output.xml'); // generating https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument and it's ability to copy nodes from one document to the other allows you to directly insert the node from the stock to the main XML.

Rather than looping to find the matching record, this also uses XPath to search for the matching record, the expression `//item[@id='boo']/stock_quantity` says find the `<stock_quantity>` element in the `<item>` element with an attribute of `id='boo'`

```
$main = new DOMDocument();
$main->load("main.xml");
$add = new DOMDocument();
$add->load("stock.xml");
$searchAdd = new DOMXPath($add);

// Find the list of items
$items = $main->getElementsByTagName("item");
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    // Exract the value of the id node
    $id = $item->getElementsByTagName("id")[0]->nodeValue;
    // Find the corresponding node in the stock file
    $stockQty = $searchAdd->evaluate("//item[@id='{$id}']/stock_quantity");
    // Import the <stock_quantity> node (and all contents)
    $copy = $main->importNode($stockQty[0], true);
    // Add the imported node
    $item->appendChild($copy);
}

echo $main->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language (like SQL) designed to transform XML files such as your specific end-use needs. Like many general-purpose languages, PHP can run XSLT 1.0  as a lower level layer using special libraries namely [php-xsl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class (requires the .ini extension enabled).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file; below assumes second XML in same directory)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ADD NODE BY CORRESPONDING id VALUE -->
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="curr_id" select="id"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('second.xml')/item_list/item[@id = $curr_id]/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(reference only first XML)*

```
// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('first.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
echo $newXML;

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = 'output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXML);
```